# "there was error running the selected code generator" when scaffolding Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to see what happen inside Identity files. Therefor, I try reveal them by scaffolding but it return me this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDyhc.png)

Comment: You can try to clear and rebuild your project, and check if any errors about package(s)  package compatibility issues in **Error List** window, then upgrade or downgrade corresponding packages before scaffolding identity.

Answer (score 0):

some of your package create conflict like(DemoAuth).you are using its latest version that is not compatible install any old version that is compatible with it.